# Intuition behind starting from the leaves instead of the parents

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to solve [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-ancestors-of-a-node-in-a-directed-acyclic-graph/) from the contest earlier today:

> You have a DAG with nodes from `0` to `n-1` and  `edges` where `edges[i] = [from_i, to_i]` denotes that there is a unidirectional edge from `from_i` to `to_i` in the graph. Return a list `answer`, where `answer[i]` is the list of ancestors of the `i`th node, sorted in **ascending** order.  
> **Input**: n = 8, edgeList = [[0,3],[0,4],[1,3],[2,4],[2,7],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],[4,6]] 
> **Output**: [[],[],[],[0,1],[0,2],[0,1,3],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3]]

[image: Graph]

I initially construct the "graph" using adjacency list representation and then calculate the *in*degree of each node.  I do a DFS with nodes with indegree `0` (since they are the *oldest* ancestors), i.e., nodes `0`, `1` and `2` in above graph. Finally, I return the result:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    unordered_map<int, unordered_set<int>> graph;
    unordered_map<int, set<int>> res;
    vector<int> degrees;

    void buildGraph(vector<vector<int>>& edges) {
        for(auto& e: edges) {
            graph[e[0]].insert(e[1]);
        }
    }

    void indegrees() {
        for(auto& s: graph) {
            for(auto e: s.second) degrees[e]++;
        }
    }
    
    void dfs(int i, vector<int>& ancestors) {
        auto neighbors=graph[i];
        for(auto& an: ancestors) res[i].insert(an);
        if(neighbors.empty()) {
            return;
        }
        
        ancestors.push_back(i);
        for(auto& n: neighbors) {
            dfs(n, ancestors);
        }
        ancestors.pop_back();
    }
    
    vector<vector<int>> getAncestors(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges) {
        buildGraph(edges);
        degrees.resize(n,0);
        indegrees();
        // cout<<"\ndegrees:\n";
        // for(auto each: degrees) cout<<each<<" ";
        // cout<<"\n";
        
        for(int i=0; i<degrees.size(); i++) {
            if(!degrees[i]) {
                vector<int> ancestors;
                dfs(i, ancestors);
            }
        }
        
        vector<vector<int>> ans(n);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            vector<int> v;
            if(!res.count(i)) {
                ans[i]=v;
                continue;
            }
            set<int>& st=res[i];
            for(auto& each: st) v.push_back(each);
            ans[i]=v;
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
};
```

This works, but times out on large inputs such as [this](https://pastebin.com/fAi2m0qG).  However, code that starts from the children ("leaves") and traverse upwards towards the ancestors gets accepted.

My question is, is there some flaw in my logic (of starting with the ancestors) which makes it slow, or is the OJ missing some test cases for the latter scenario (of starting with the leaves)?

Comment: Your algorithm is quadratic on this worst case: [0,1],[0,2], ... [0,100], [1,101], [2, 101], ...[100, 101], [101, 102], [102,103], ... [199,200]. That is, a heavy fan at the top, then a long tail at the bottom. The tail is `n/2` long, and you are traversing it `n/2` times. I expect the traversal from leaves up would have the same problem if the graph is reversed, with the long tail at the top and the fan at the bottom. In both cases, the pathological behavior can be avoided by teaching `dfs` to keep track of visited nodes and skip them the second time round.

Comment: As a minor improvement, `auto neighbors=graph[i];` makes a deep copy. `auto& neighbors=graph[i];` would be sufficient.

Comment: And in the final loop, `auto& v = ans[i];`, so you populate the vector in place, rather then off to the side and then making a copy. Or at least, `ans[i]=std::move(v);`

Comment: Actually, I take it back. On this pathological case, the output itself is of quadratic size, so quadratic time is inevitable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, so if I understand you correctly, the issue is missing test cases for the bottom up traversal of the tree, right?  IMO, both should have the same complexity.  I do a DFS in `O(nodes)` from nodes with indegree==0, while people do a DFS from each node and yet their code is ACed; I don't know why.

Comment: Possibly. Off the top, I don't see why the direction should matter, as the problem appears symmetrical: whatever paths a top-down algorithm takes, a graph exists that would force a bottom-up algorithm to take the same paths.

Comment: Okay.  Also, I think my algorithm is `O(nodes^2)`; is this correct?

Comment: Like I said, graphs exist where the correct output is `O(n^2)` in size, and so the algorithm can't possibly be faster than `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, my algo is `O(n^2)` (not worse than that)?

Comment: Probably `O(n^2 log n)`; insertion into `std::set` got to have a `log n` in there somewhere.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense.  I have a feeling the constant is higher which is resulting in TLE.

Comment: Another minor improvement: `for(auto& an: ancestors) res[i].insert(an);` could be written as `res[i].insert(ancestors.begin(), ancestors.end());` This does a lookup in `res` only once, and it's possible `std::set` is able to optimize bulk insertion better.

Comment: A possible different approach. Apply a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to the graph (linear in the number of nodes plus edges). Then walk nodes in this topological order, from roots to leaves. For each node with the set of parents `P`, the list of ancestors is the set union of ancestors of nodes in `P` (already computed, as parents have already been visited) plus `P` itself. Merging sorted lists can be done in linear time, so this should shave off the `log n` factor.